# Passing user meta through comment form

Tags: comments, customization

I want to create a hidden field in the user comment form storing the logged in users info (already created a custom field at registration) so I can pass it to the comments section to display on the website.

How can I create a hidden field and display it in the recorded comment section, or is there a better way of 'stamping' a piece of user meta data in a comment? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Comments are already associated with a user ID for logged in users. You ought to be able to pull anything you want using that ID.

Comment: Maybe I'm making this too complicated...OK how do I display a piece of user meta data in a user comment? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect that change of focus and I will put together a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your theme's `comments.php` file, you should see a call to `wp_list_comments`. If that has a callback parameter-- something like this `array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' )`-- then your theme has its own comment display function. Find that function. It is probably in `function.php` but no promises. If not, you need to make one. That function controls the comment display. Inside that function do something like this:

```
  $user = get_user_by('login',$comment->comment_author);
  if ($user) {
    $umeta = get_user_meta($user->ID);
    echo '################################';
    var_dump($umeta);
    echo '################################';
  }
```

And you should have what you need-- just a matter of formatting it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: Thanks for that but a bit lost...I found wp_list_comments parameter but no function in my functions.php (I use Woothemes Canvas theme) so unsure how to create the full function. Your code to go inside the function - in the echo part I presume that's where you specify the exact user meta? Sorry I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: I actually got it from this code:global $post;
$id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
?>
<?php
$field='industry';
echo the_author_meta($field, $id );
?> Thanks for your help though.